# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'next/image'

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Nextjs app and trying to use the `Image` feature.

I am importing the dependencies like so:

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
```

but getting this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'next/image'

only for `next/image` and not for `next/link` which is confusing me.

Comment: What version of next are you using. If it's the latest one I'd suggest reinstalling it, if it's not, upgrade your next version

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved by

- Updating Nextjs using `npm install react@latest react-dom@latest`, **[This solution can break your project make sure you need to update]**
- Ensuring you're importing `next/image` **in small letters** not
  `next/Image` in capital letters.

Comment: Great! Thanks. BTW: If you think it's about `module` and `moduleResolution` in `tsconfig.json` you're partly right... Make sure you know what you're doing. In this case you're probably fine with `module: "CommonJS"` and `moduleResolution: "node"`. TBH I don't get why "nodenext" fails (I'm using Node LTS, 18+ though) and IMO "nodenext" should be the correct resolution. Probably has to do with `target: "ES5"` but in the spec is written from TS > 4.7 I should use `nodenext` which errors. Any ideas? Will find out soon anyway  Just want others to keep that in mind additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Replace tsconfig.json with this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"],
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```